# std::set метод insert() крашит програму

Tags: c++, строки, vector, set

Есть у меня код:

```
void fill_list(std::list<std::set<std::string>>& s,std::set<std::string>& all_toys,const int n){
    std::vector<std::string> vect;
    for(auto it = all_toys.begin(); it != all_toys.end(); it++){
        vect.push_back(*it);
    }

    auto it = s.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < all_toys.size(); i++){
            int tmp = rand() % vect.size() + 0;
            it->insert(vect[tmp]);
        }
    it++;
    }

}
```

Его суть в том что у меня есть список сетов,и каждый сет нужно рандомно заполнить элементами из общего сета где храняться строки,но почему-то при добавлении строки в сет програма крашиться,что не так?

n - кол-во елементов в списке сетов

Вызывающий код:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    std::set<std::string> all_toys = {"Auto", "Bear", "Gun", "airplane" , "doll", "house", "guitar", "dog"};
    std::cout << "Enter n: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    
    std::list<std::set<std::string>> lst;
    
    fill_list(lst,all_toys,n);
    print_list(lst);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что интересно если пару раз запустить то есть вероятность что програма не крашнет.Помогите я не понимаю что не так

Comment: Что не так, это долгая история, но если  сказать кратко вы не понимаете что делаете, из за этого получается ерунда. У вас есть множество, и почему появилась необходимость взять и заполнить его элементы в другой контейнер вектор, не понятно. all_toys есть  множество упорядоченных элементов а s есть ссылка на список подобных множеств.  vect это вектор, и вы всех перемешиваете в одно понятие и условно ваши команды абсолютно не понятны и  являются источником долгой дискуссии.  Конкретный бред, вот и логично крашится  программа. Еще раз задумайтесь  о том, что хотите делать.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код который вызывает функцию. Особенно интересно как соотносятся `n` и `s`.

Comment: Хорошо,тогда давайте переформулирую вопрос,как мне можно из одного сета заполнить рандомно n разных сетов?

Comment: Тоесть у меня есть сет строк,мне надо n сетов заполнить элементами этого сета

Comment: std::list имеет нулевую длину. А вы по нему `n` раз итерируетесь. Вот и вся не долга.

Comment: Спасибо большое, не усмотрел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том что вы итерируетесь по пустому списку.

Вот вариант, который решает вашу задачу по-другому. Функция `distribute` выделяет вектор множеств требуемой длины и распределяет элементы исходного множества в случайные элементы вектора:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::set<std::string>> distribute(
    const std::set<std::string> source,
    int n
) {
    std::vector<std::set<std::string>> d(n);

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, n - 1);

    for (auto it = source.begin(); it != source.end(); ++it) {
        d[distr(gen)].insert(*it);
    }

    return d;
}

int main(){
    std::set<std::string> all_toys = {
        "Auto", "Bear", "Gun", "airplane", "doll", "house", "guitar", "dog"
    };
    std::cout << "Enter n: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    std::vector<std::set<std::string>> d = distribute(all_toys, n);
    for (auto it = d.begin(); it != d.end(); ++it) {
        std::copy(
            it->begin(),
            it->end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " ")
        );
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

по пробуй

it->insert(vect[tmp-1]);

Comment: И если `tmp == 0`, то что получится?

Comment: ну мне просто кажется что 'tmp' в какой-то момент рандомом выпадает на максимальный элемент вектора, а т.к. 'vect.size()' считает не от ноля а просто количество элементов, следовательно если в массиве 4 элемента где индекс последнего '= 3' а 'vect.size() == 4' то мы банально выйдем за его пределы

Comment: Програма всегда крашит на первой итерации

Comment: Я вручную туда подставлял индекс,не помогает

Comment: @User12345, Добавьте в вопрос вызывающий код.

Comment: Падение не в `insert`, а в `it->`.

Comment: Добавил вызывающий код